# FFMPEG: How to encode for seekable video at high key frame interval

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, requestanimationframe, webm

I'm looking for an ffmpeg comand that's best used if I'm controlling a video to mouse control on "requestAnimationFrame". Basically, it needs to be fast-seeking and encoded at a high key frame interval. I can't seem to nail down what parameters aid in fast-seeking and high key frames.

thanks!
Johnny

Comment: What you are looking for is called intra-frame: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intra-frame_coding

Answer (score 19):

If you're encoding x264 (mp4), try ([docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)):

```
ffmpeg -i file -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=25 [preset/rate control options] out.mp4
```

If you're encoding vp9 (webm), try ([docs](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide) or [backup docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20230725174849/http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide)):

```
ffmpeg -i file -c:v libvpx-vp9 -g 25 [speed/rate control options] out.webm
```

Both commands will place a new keyframe every 25 frames. If you want more than that (e.g. one keyframe every frame), then perhaps you don't care about compression as much as you care about speed, and it may be worth looking into intra-only codecs such as [FFv1](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/FFV1).

Comment: My ffmpeg needed -x264opts keyint=25 (using =,not :)

Comment: docs link not working